# Combine histogram bars and 2D dot plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to create a plot similar to this, where histogram bins are plotted along each axis of some randomly distributed data from a csv-file:

[image: example plot]

Ideally, the histogram bars would be mirrored along the their main axis, so that unlike in this example, the histogram orgin is on the axis. How can this or something similar be done in pgfplots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to be a duplicate of this thread: [Scatterplot with marginal histograms using pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193059/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-using-pgfplots)

And you can do this in R easily, this thread gives two ways of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2

Comment: Yes, the pgfplot solution looks promsing. Thanks for the quick answer. Apparently I did not have the right keywords to find it myself