# Loglog scatterplot with marginal histograms using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to make a scatterplot with marginal histograms, similar to what was done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193059/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-using-pgfplots), except I would like to have the axes be loglog. I tried this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    /pgfplots/scale only axis,
    /pgfplots/width=6cm,
    /pgfplots/height=6cm
]

% The scatterplot
\begin{loglogaxis}[
    name=main axis % Name the axis, so we can position the histograms relative to this axis
]
\addplot [only marks, mark size=1.5] table {random.dat};
\end{loglogaxis}


% The histogram for the x axis
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
    anchor=south west,
    at=(main axis.north west),
    height=2cm,
    xtick=\empty
]
\addplot [
    hist={data=x}, % By default, the y values would be used for calculating the histogram
    fill=gray!50
] table {random.dat};
\end{semilogxaxis}


% The histogram for the y axis
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    anchor=north west,
    at=(main axis.north east),
    width=2cm,
    ytick=\empty
]
\addplot [
    % For swapping the x and y axis, we have to change a couple of options...
    hist={handler/.style={xbar interval}}, % ... use bars instead of columns ...
    x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{rawy}, % ... interpret the x values of the histogram as y values 
    y filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{rawx}, % ... and vice versa.
    fill=gray!50,
] table {random.dat};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

But, I get this:

[image]

`random.dat`

```
-1.034556182675299  -1.088642639137081
-1.062642392542183  -1.730800229782827
2.112061236824446   0.4213052508263926
0.2081414092873681  0.1178499381944298
0.9996769569924666  2.315473894804006
-1.860016360692352  -1.80583336044917
1.73369575407621    1.368173161256781
-0.7429308663836777 -0.320890575343841
-0.1979146573912954 -0.4365080476459813
0.4716501224453675  0.7643018830581477
1.174380766341545   2.934973750859623
0.6901490963059546  0.5055566964399909
-0.5225274899322595 -2.336402501215872
-0.04752524566243782    0.9918382785064426
-0.02545715784606146    0.6179587619354383
-1.692445541259954  0.3233798554565113
-0.230370492420001  -0.5392176955328299
0.6038059014476774  0.6821182440059813
-1.076804609398595  -0.9837056700351312
-0.1857789391152365 -1.136939273688752
-0.258208790502279  -0.1805152973444488
-0.7195599671240704 -0.8479059081735516
1.092570499347843   2.00377759530567
-0.2696062294740929 -1.132458520464889
-0.8269924788320669 -1.927117798964017
-0.1515366074290889 0.0230071339470114
-0.7103213503616422 -1.403963958892485
0.8829530102950023  1.857490683255044
1.05866349916398    0.7198501681466614
1.096466379804495   1.086525729480579
-1.32303169638362   -0.1533202087887688
0.3739354686781606  -0.03156926687636152
1.489342072707867   2.1872117646764
-0.224900534871041  0.8163766108669269
-1.587347359907595  -2.086313437701529
1.464685243093322   1.374198533145222
-1.267338251647083  -1.195439494319655
0.1251550598405904  -0.7780312340895389
0.8180551984329997  0.3179571635755173
-0.7259672309991982 1.024286153382652
-0.6347060382424617 -1.995450039583252
-0.1275879531600163 -0.9701248657421334
-1.035154214040656  -0.4345218059923297
1.112830442579158   0.9110796108289648
0.1403940614228557  0.3930966756241305
-0.5990597080153418 -2.147831326516866
-0.7035026366060558 0.8009160824851748
1.090688799524646   0.9976237777767307
0.4195835157027016  1.612462920311422
-0.2394595550413869 0.1403177798195741
1.444637305245141   1.793725253759151
0.2510826487708296  -0.9172402778780173
1.050970237168825   0.3429458548719517
-0.1547669371612623 -0.2953877678347505
-0.7077964330012175 -1.577410023672865
-1.281557650915341  -0.7019585910796728
-0.6925092860234755 0.1296573951006644
0.8917492915726694  0.8043114131875437
1.376261454402816   0.2900129349329763
0.6801069893656928  1.430824000405047
-0.2484495635256442 -0.8330824219547133
-0.4795979211826638 -2.492087400741266
1.514924124643029   2.54293071805945
0.622154322642365   0.6249697071569896
0.6434471902987018  0.6624842288917316
2.009568724897284   1.295013757951034
-0.1611358858000567 0.5972825224341278
-0.4958826045353003 0.6552123781234539
-1.546608039056112  -3.092251590256194
0.01963903742918456 -0.6358681023557348
-1.217115357590687  -1.427228304202919
-0.03318482365966646    1.244676317998937
0.1441806659737843  -0.3917848725994295
0.7327139102596605  0.179905661977997
-0.2221623219999036 2.013269450880812
-1.766951404705671  -2.055174273761125
0.1820313811963468  0.5457314419902735
1.114346122011083   1.207326114691013
-1.673897686055655  0.04471554925774202
-1.88098566831986   -0.342043266131189
0.6156730283674012  0.5612745693047205
-0.4702721814316267 -0.04543544172550568
-1.732071951319274  -3.252174730928117
0.9137493443444534  1.152947925633689
0.6178392723810281  0.4132280927224983
0.2967867922623997  -0.07841919518125928
1.396752176208157   1.878892768919695
0.6920887677132427  -0.6696496175333456
-0.2888105031888556 0.05544842238228853
0.8817399280652953  -0.5140856584657298
0.8830220191165575  0.6892944908867348
0.1547642100344178  -0.1064069449067648
0.1267761409114066  0.2672715326585765
-0.1738327099717071 -0.3007997877815971
-0.2222141791185833 -0.3913443288370902
0.3135248241729749  -1.076410808299793
-1.042708487268197  1.133781748500934
0.172987850082249   1.793537418388745
-1.919319965387205  -0.9735790026351395
-1.837375345395248  -0.6512990567395325
```

Comment: Could you add a dummy `random.dat`, or make `pgfplotstable` table with some values, so people don't have to generate the data themselves?

Comment: Done. I just copied over the data from the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193059/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-using-pgfplots).

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Do you want bins that have an equal width in linear scale (and thus show not equally thick in log scale) or do you want to have bins that have an equal width in log scale (and thus also look equally thick in log scale)?

Comment: Either is fine, but preference for equal width on log scale. The issue right now is that this is not consistent in the plot above.